# Brainfuck cell print loop

Tags: loops, brainfuck

How would one go about creating a loop in Brainfuck to print a cell "x" number of times?

For example:

```
----[-->+++<]>.
```

This will print "z" but I want to repeat "z" for 100+ times, how can I do that without using "." in succession to make my code as concise as possible?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the cell to the value of `z` without outputting: `----[-->+++<]>`, then move one cell right and start a loop of a 100 times: `>++++++++++[>++++++++++[**commands here**-]<-]`.

Since we moved two cells right to create the nested 10x10 loop, we move two cells left to print, then go back to keep the loop running with `<<.>>`, and finally we get

```
----[-->+++<]>>++++++++++[>++++++++++[<<.>>-]<-]
```

[Test it here!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fFwiidXXttLW1bWLtQBQURCOzbWz07Ox0Y210Y///BwA)

Comment: Very neat. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want a "Counter Cell" that counts down every time you repeat it

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++        //some stuff to set cell 0 to a value
>++++++++++        //go to counter cell, sets it to the amount you want to repeat the value for
[<.>-]             //print cell 0 once then decrease the counter by 1
                   //once counter is 0 then stop printing
```